# Intent.createChooser() display style?

Tags: android, android-intent

Per the [Google training doc](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) on sending content, the result of `Intent.createChooser()` is a list:

[Can't post images because I'm new. See above url.]

However, when I implement it I get more of a grid view, as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507116/android-can-createchooser-filter-apps-by-type).

Is the chooser display style Android version-specific? I've noticed that Dropbox running on my 4.2.2 device shows the list-style display. Perhaps they implemented a custom chooser or am I unaware of an Intent.putExtra() option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That Intent Chooser UI has changed in various releases of Android.

Specifically, previous to Jelly Bean (4.1), it was implemented as a dark list.  In Jelly Bean, it was changed to be a light grid.

Take a look at the screenshots from [Android Police's article on Jelly Bean UI changes](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/08/13/getting-to-know-android-4-1-part-4-stuff/):
[image: Old style of Chooser]
[image: New style of Chooser]

Note also that Commonsware wrote about the change and recommended developers to change their own custom chooser in his blog entry [The Linkify Problem: The Detection and the Mitigation](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/07/24/linkify-problem-detection-mitigation.html), where he noted that it might be related to a patent:

> Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean), for example, slightly changes the chooser, to show a set of icons in a row or grid for the chooser, instead of a classic vertically-oriented menu-ish list. Whether this change was introduced based upon this patent, we may never know.

Also, I think Dropbox probably created their own UI for their chooser.

Answer (score 5):

The intent chooser belongs to the system! It will appear according to your device's theme. you cant change that unless you modify the system UI.About Dropbox they might have created chooser that actually doesnt belong to the system. They might have themed an activity to look like a chooser and sent an intent to the custom chooser.

Comment: If you want to implement your own, this is the class you need http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryBroadcastReceivers(android.content.Intent, int)